# Is a per port graft possible?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I'm attempting to serve a number of small Flask applications with the CherryPy server. I would like to expose one over SSL without exposing all routes over that port. Is it possible to provide routes on a per port basis?

Maybe something like...

```python
cherrypy.tree.graft(mdm_server, "/", 443)
cherrypy.tree.graft(admin_server, "/admin", 80)
cherrypy.tree.graft(acct_server, "/accounting", 80)
```

Or..

```python
cherrypy.tree.graft(server1, mdm_server, "/")
cherrypy.tree.graft(server2, admin_server, "/admin")
cherrypy.tree.graft(server2, acct_server, "/accounting")
```

Comment: not sure why/how you want to involve flask, when you use cherrypy. You can access the port with the parameter `cherrypy.request.local.port` when handling the request and refuse access if it's the wrong one.

Comment: I think @chancyk means smth like server listenting to several ports with cherrypy.dispatch.VirtualHost dispatcher set up: http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/deploy.html?highlight=virtualhost#virtual-hosting

Comment: @576i I'm not sure about using `cherrypy.request.local.port` since the apps being hosted are foreign Flask WSGI applications. It's a legacy application that was just using the Flask dev server internally, so I hoping to get the CherryPy server working before trying to migrate the actual apps.

Comment: @webKnjaZ I think VirtualHost would work if I didn't have a second SSL enabled CherryPy server in play, which seems to serve anything added with `cherrypy.tree.graft` by default. Basically I'm trying to restrict anything to port 443 to a specific app.